# jQuery .one is executing callback function several times

Tags: javascript, jquery, animate.css

I'm using [Animate.css](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css) for my animation with jQuery n-th element.
Here is the fraction of my code.

```js
$("tr td:nth-child("+columnIndex+")").addClass("animated flip").one('animationend oAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd webkitAnimationEnd', function(){
      $("tr td:nth-child("+columnIndex+")" ).removeClass("highlight");
      animationFlag++;
      alert("Getting called several times");
    });
```

My problem is that callback function that increases the animationFlag is being called several times. Actually, it's getting called number of rows times in the table. Is there any way to call it just once.

Comment: It will be called once per flip element.

Comment: That's because `$("tr td:nth-child")` is returning a jQuery collection and `one()` is operating on each of those to find `one` of...

Comment: Is there a way to make it call once for all nth child?

Comment: You could try attaching the `one()` event handler to the table.

Comment: Thanks, @Taplar I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around for my question. I just introduce a variable 'called' to keep track of callback function being called.

```js
var called = false;
    $("tr td:nth-child("+columnIndex+")" ).addClass("highlight");
    $("tr td:nth-child("+columnIndex+")").addClass("animated flip").one('animationend oAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd webkitAnimationEnd', function(){
      if(called==false){
        $("tr td:nth-child("+columnIndex+")" ).removeClass("highlight");
        animationFlag++;
        alert('hahhahahaha working');
        called = true;
      }else{
        return;
      }
      
    });
```

Thank you.

Comment: Kinda defeats the purpose of using `one()` :|